# Searching a file for the last match of a regexp in bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I'm awful at bash and need to write a script to find the last instance of a regexp in a .log file. and return the entire line. Is this possible with sed or would I have to use awk?

Thanks!

Comment: It's possible with both, but easiest with `grep regex file | tail -n 1`

Comment: It is possible with bash, sed or awk.  If you'd like to make a go at it, I'm sure folks here would be happy to help you debug your work.

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks, what does the tail -n 1 do?

Comment: Quoting `man`: `tail -- display the last part of a file` - in this case, the last line of `stdin`.

Comment: @Gus Bookmark [explainshell.com](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=tail+-n+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find all matches with `grep` and get the last one with `tail`:

```
grep regex file | tail -n 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it so:

```
sed -nr '/YOUR_REGEXP/h; ${g;p}' INPUT_FILE
```

grep will consume your memory by storing absolutely useless data: you dont need all matches except of last but it will be stored in memory, but only last of occurences/matches will be printed by tail -n1.
And yes, GNU sed is faster then grep and support more complex regexp's.

Comment: Protip: always keep a civil tone just in case you're wrong. On 10M lines (693MB) with 150k matching lines (11MB), your solution uses 1MB rss and 8 seconds, while mine uses 1.5MB rss and 2 seconds. i.e. yours is four times slower with extremely marignal memory savings.